# Deselect all ag-grid rows after quick filter is applied and rows data change

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I need to deselect all rows from the grid when quick filter is applied:
`quickFilterText={this.props.quickFilterText}`
or data was changed:
`rowData={this.rowData}`

It should be done within `ag-grid` I can't manipulate this in wrapper component. Is there a way to do so? Some event like `onQuickFilterApplied` or something like this? I can't find any in docs.

Comment: Should be possible to do with `api.deselectAll()`: `https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-selection/#grid-selection-api`. On events like `onRowDataUpdated` or `onFilterChanged` from `https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-events/`, or have I misunderstood and you are somehow unable to use grid events?

Comment: That's true, however I can't use `onRowDataUpdated`  or `onFilterChanged` because those events are also called in other situations. I need to deselect rows only on quick search.

Comment: Does `onFilterChanged` trigger on quick filter change? If so it might solve your issue, if not - I would store quick filter value in state and compare it on grid update.